# Why does intellij print "void" when using evaluate log for a breakpoint?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I wrote this Java code in intellij:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1,1,1,1,1,1};
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
            a[i]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Next I set a breakpoint inside the for-loop like so.

[image: Breakpoint]

Next I go to the "view breakpoints" menu, which can be accessed by ctrl+shift+f8 and enter these settings for my breakpoint.

[image: Breakpoint settings]

Then I hit the debug button and my output is this:

```
void
1
void
1
void
1
void
1
void
1
void
1
```

Why is intellij printing "void" in the output?

Comment: "Evaluate and log" means that it automatically prints the result. You're basically doing `System.out.println(System.out.println(a[1]))`.

Comment: @JJJ  the question should be why it is printing `1` in console ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin ...because that's the value of `a[i]`?

Comment: @JJJ but we are not saying to log the value of `a[i]`. We are saying to  log  return value of `System.out.println(a[i])` . So, why ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin ...because `System.out.println(a[i])` prints the value of `a[i]` before it returns?

Comment: @JJJ I have written System.out.println at work, when I wanted to log some request info(it's a large project so I can't provide an example here), and it didn't print "void" for some reason, that's why I was confused here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the `println()` method is declared as `void`. When you evaluate an expression in debug mode it generates a literal value from the expression's result. So, when you evaluate the expression `System.out.println(a[i])`, you are really telling the debugger to print the contents of the method's return value, which happens to be `void`.  It so happens that within the method an additional `println(int)` method call is performed, making the actual evaluated expression essentially equivalent to this puedocode `System.out.println(System.out.println(a[i]))` (though of course in actuality Java doesn't treat `void` as a true type, so you wouldn't be able to actually execute the code as written).

The JavaDoc for the `PrintStream.println(int)` method is available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-int-) (for Java 9) and you can view the source code of the method [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.println(int)) (from OpenJDK JDK version 8u40-b25 aka Java 8).

---

Consider the following methods:

```
void evaluatesToVoid(){
    final int[] a = {1,1};
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
    
    return;
}

int evaluatesToSeven(){
     return 7;
}
```

When you evaluate a method call which returns a valid return type, for example the primitive type `int`, you will get the method's return value.

Using evaluate and log on `evaluatesToVoid()` would print this:

```
void
1
1
```

Using evaluate and log on `evaluatesToSeven()` would print this:

```
7
```